# struts2 when action returns input included actions in freemarker do not call execute

Tags: struts2

We have a number of Freemarker pages that have action calls within them, for example:

The problem we are having is that if the action that renders the page returns INPUT for any reason then the execute() method of the included action does not get called. Instead, only the validate method gets called.  This means that the logic for the action is not executed. I would have thought that the included actions invocation should be independent of the result of the 'parent' action.

To workaround we are having to add input result mappings to the header action mapping to exactly the same as success mappings, and also explictly call execute within the validate method.  This is unclean and seems wrong.

Is this a struts2 bug or is there something I am missing?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: If Validation fails, the request is handed off to the "input" result template, if it succeeds, it is handed off to the "success" result; seems like you are expecting both cases to go to the success page.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Yes for certain actions i.e. ones that are included in the top of pages such as the header action mentioned above, we would always want the success template executed.  I am not sure why actions included in a page would inherit the result of the action that served the page.